# Using Mathematical Induction to Prove that $f^n (x) = 3^n e^{3x}$, where $f^n (x)$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$, and $n$ is a natural number.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Here is the question that I am not sure if I am doing right.

> Let $f(x) = e^{3x}$ and suppose $f^n (x)$ represents the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. Use mathematical induction to prove $f^n (x) = 3^n e^{3x}$, where $n$ is a natural number.

And here is my attempt:

First, we have to show that the base case is true. So for $n = 1$,

We know that $f'(x) = 3e^{3x}$. We want to see if $f^1 (x)$ is the same. So

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= f^1 (x) \\
3e^{3x} &= 3^1 e^{3x} \\
3e^{3x} &= 3e^{3x}
\end{align*}

Since LS $\equiv$ RS for $n = 1$, the base case is true.

For the inductive step, we want to assume that $f^n(x) = 3^n e^{3x}$ is true for $n = k$, such that $f^k(x) = 3^k e^{3x}$. Then we want to show that this is also true for $n = k + 1$.

\begin{align*}
f^{k+1}(x) &= 3^{k + 1}e^{3x} \\
&= (3)^k(3)^1e^{3x} \\
&= (3)^1(3^k e^{3x}) \\
&= 3f^k(x)
\end{align*}

I don't know if this is correct or not, or if I am on the right track. Some help or some suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have$f^{(k)}=3^ke^{3x}$
And have to prove$f^{(k+1)}=3^{k+1}e^{3x}$.

To do that we just need to take derivative of $f^{(k)}(x)$:

$$f^{(k+1)}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[f^{(k)}(x)]=(3^ke^{3x})'=3^k\times 3e^{3x}=3^{k+1}e^{3x}$$
It is done!

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped you.